# Special Functions prerequisites

Tags: special-functions

I want to study special functions for the first time and I've seen that S. F. sometimes are solutions for differential equations. Do I have to learn certain topics other than calculus before studying S. F. for the first time?

Comment: Complex analysis.

Comment: Special functions often have several equivalent definitions. Only some of these definitions involve differential equations, although often the **original** definition was a differential equation.

Comment: @Somos 
So Differential Equations is the elementary topic, then it depends if the professor will give us other equivalent definitions?

Comment: Consult [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) or [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/) for equivalent definitions.